# const trait bound not allowed in non-trait impl in rust

Tags: generics, rust

I am experimenting with const trait bounds, and I have noticed that while it is possible to define a `const` trait bound on a `const` fn, it is not possible to do so on an `impl` (not an `impl const Trait`) where all the functions within the `impl` that rely on the `const` bound are themselves `const`.

For example, say I define

```rs
struct Foo<T>(T);
```

then this code compiles

```rs
const fn add<T: ~const Add>(a: Foo<T>, b: Foo<T>) -> Foo<T> {
    a + b
}
```

whereas this code produces the error "`~const` is not allowed here
only allowed on bounds on traits' associated types and functions, const fns, const impls and its associated functions"

```rs
impl<T: ~const Add> Foo<T> {
    const fn add(a: Foo<T>, b: Foo<T>) -> Foo<T> {
        a + b
    }
}
```

I understand that this is because at the moment I am not telling the compiler that every function that uses `T` in the `impl` will be `const`. Is there any way of providing this guarantee, without having to workaround by adding a `where T: ~const Add` to every function in the `impl`?